# ¿Es posible generar una tabla con DAX desde Power Pivot en Excel?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

Me pregunto si es posible generar una tabla con el lenguaje de fórmulas DAX directamente desde Power Pivot. Imagina por ejemplo una expresión como esta: =VALUES(Clientes[Nombre]). Esta fórmula me devolverá todos los nombres contenidos en la columna "Nombre" de la tabla "Clientes". Si utilizo esta expresión como medida, obviamente no funciona pues va a devolver más de un valor, y eso es incompatible con el concepto de medida. Hasta ahí todo claro. Pero yo quiero utilizar esa expresión para generar una tabla que contenga los nombres de mis clientes. Algo así en Power BI funciona, ya que cuenta con la opción de "Crear tabla". No sé si hay lo mismo en Power Pivot. Yo no lo he encontrado. La única forma de añadir tablas en Power Pivot es a través del administrador del modelo de datos, y que esos datos procedan de algún origen, ya sea una tabla de Excel, una conexión con BBDD, etc. Espero haberme explicado bien :D. ¿Alguien sabe si es posible? Gracias.